Changing header bar button on login into logout in React JS?
I am creating a template and its frontend only using React and Next.js . So I have dashboard with header bar and login button. Once logged in , the login button should be logout and also the links in header should be different. Moreover I have MUI drawer side nav, that should also be only visible once logged in .
For logging in I have hard coded email and pw , as I don't have any database .
Loggin form
import Dashboard from "@/app/(routes)/dashboard/page";
import { LockOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import {
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  Box,
  Avatar,
  Typography,
  TextField,
  Button,
  Grid,
} from "@mui/material";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";


const LoginForm = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
 

  const handleLogin = () => {   

    if (email === 'aa@yahoo.com' && password === 'aaa') {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);       
        alert('Login successful!');
      } else {
        alert('Invalid email or password');
      }

    console.log('Email:', email);
    console.log('Password:', password); 
   
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
  };

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Dashboard/>
   
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            mt: 20,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: "primary.light" }}>
            <LockOutlined />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography variant="h5">Login</Typography>
          <Box sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoFocus
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />

            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="password"
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setPassword(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <Button
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
              onClick={handleLogin}
            >
              Login
            </Button>
            <Grid container justifyContent={"flex-end"}>
              <Grid item>
              <Link href="/signup" passHref>
               Don't have an account? Register</Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;

**Header Component**
"use client"

import * as React from 'react';
import MuiAppBar, { AppBarProps as MuiAppBarProps } from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import SideNav from '../SideNav/SideNav';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

type Anchor = 'left' ;
const drawerWidth = 240;


const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
}));


interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
  open?: boolean;
}
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));



export default function Header() {

 const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static"  open={open} sx={{ bgcolor: 'primary.dark', color: 'secondary.dark'}}> 
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: 'none' })}}
            // onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}      
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}    
          >            
            <MenuIcon /> 
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>          
          <Drawer
           open={open}            
            > 
            <DrawerHeader >
              <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
              </IconButton>              
            </DrawerHeader>
            <SideNav/>              
          </Drawer>          
          <Button color="inherit">Login or Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}


You can use react context to store information about login, for example you can create a folder context and create a file loginContext.tsx inside that folder:
// loginContext.tsx
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"

export const LoginContext = createContext({ // create the context
   isLoggedIn: false,
   updateLogin: () => {}
})
// create the context provider
const LoginProvider= ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode[]}) => {
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

   function updateLogin() {
       setIsLoggedIn(!isLoggedIn);
   }
   
   return (
       <LoginContext.Provider value={{isLoggedIn, updateLogin}}>
           {children}
       </LoginContext.Provider>
   )
}


you will have to wrap both your LoginForm and Header components inside the context provider, for example, inside your Component1.tsx, Component2.tsx components:
// Component1.tsx
import { LoginContext, LoginProvider } from "./context/loginContext" // you might need to change the module specifiers
import { Header } from "./Header"

export function Component1() {
    return(
        <LoginProvider>
             <Header />
        </LoginProvider>
    )
}

// Component2.tsx
import { LoginForm } from "./LoginForm"

export function Component2() {
    return(
        <LoginProvider>
             <LoginForm/>
        </LoginProvider>
    )
}

As you can see, if they are not in the same parent component, you can't rely on props. And then you can use the context you have created, inside your Header component:
import { useContext } from "react"
import { LoginContext } from "./context/loginContext"
/* ...Other imports */

function Header() {
     const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(LoginContext);
     return (
         /* your jsx */
     )
}

this will allow you to access the isLoggedIn in both Header and LoginForm.
For the texts inside the login button and the header links, you can use if else statements or ternary operators:
// LoginForm
/* imports */
import { useContext } from "react"
import { LoginContext } from "./context/loginContext"

export function LoginForm() {
     const { isLoggedIn, updateLogin } = useContext(LoginContext);
     const handleLogin = () => {   
          if (email === 'aa@yahoo.com' && password === 'aaa') {
            updateLogin();// minor change, setState to the context function 
            alert('Login successful!');
          } else {
            alert('Invalid email or password');
          }

        console.log('Email:', email);
        console.log('Password:', password); 
     };
     return(
          /* ... */
           <Button
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
              onClick={handleLogin}
            >
              {isLoggedIn ? "Login" : "Logout"} {/* this is the logic of the button text */}
            </Button>
          /* ... */
      )
}


This way you can ensure that the button text changes according to your isLoggedIn state, you can do the same for other header links.

It is not letting me create any folder or file with the name 'context' , I am using Next.js and have layout.tsx

I don't understand how you can't create a folder, what IDE are you using, can you provide more information?

There was some issue with my directory. I have managed to create but getting this error 'LoginProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'Context<{ isLoggedIn: boolean; updateLogin: () => void; }>' is not a valid JSX element type.ts(2786)

There's a problem in my code, i forgot to export the LoginProvider from the loginContext.tsx file, also the file extension has to be .tsx  along with other components i mentioned
